# Best way to launch a process and block until it is finished

Tags: python

I'm told subprocess.Popen does not block, so the process runs in the background and your python program does not wait until it has finished.  However, this is not what I want.

I'm having my program call into an external python program, which I have no control over.  It does not return any return codes, just runs, operates on files, and finishes.  I want to call this and only continue my python program when that call has completed.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) or [wait](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) on the subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `call` method from subprocess.

> subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
>   Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return the returncode attribute.

see → http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use the `communicate` method:
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Also have a look at the `wait` method, it states why most of the time you should use communicate instead:
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait

Comment: most of the time? Only if I work with pipes. If I just run a command and want to wait for it, I don't need that.

Comment: Most of the time because one should not ignore the output of a process and pipes (are in my opinion) the most convenient way to handle it. And that leads to using `communicate`.

Comment: Yes and no. Normally yes, but if a process outputs (or expects) megabytes of data, it is most of the time better to fetch the data piece by piece instead of putting it all at once, like `communicate()` does...

Comment: the "most of the time" is linked to "not ignore the output". If to use `communicate()` or to handle by myself is IMHO to be determined by the amount of data to be expected.